# Output putStrLn throws Error when running in the command line

Tags: haskell

I am not understanding why this code is not outputting. I keep getting errors that say: parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets) 
                  putStrLn "Enter how many numbers:"

```
 main = do
    putStrLn "Enter how many numbers:" -- clearer
    listlen <- getLine 
    if (listlen < 100)
    then 
    putStrLn "Enter a number: "
    numberString <- getLine
    let numberInt =(read numberString :: Int)
    print (numberInt)
    else 
        putStrLn " Error: listlen must be less than 100"
```

Comment: What is the line number for which you get the error?

Comment: it says. test3.hs:4:23 error:

Answer (score 1):

When I pasted your example into my editor, the line that failed was the one after "then". If you add a "do" after "then", that error goes away.

So:

```
then do
putStrLn "Enter a number: "
```

...etc.

Comment: thank you so much! that cleared up my confusion on that. I now have the following error: test3.hs.4:17: error: * no instant for Num String arising from the literal '100'

Comment: `getLine` is type `IO String`, that is: returns the line as a `String` (within the IO monad). So it doesn't return a number. So you can't compare `listlen < 100`. you need to convert the `String` to a number: use `read`.

Answer (score 1):

The `listlen` is `String` type that cannot compare to `100`. It need use `read` to convert it to number:

```
if (read listlen < 100)
...
```